# Tracking session length in android

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, mixpanel

I am trying to track the length of a user session (with Mixpanel- but this question is not about Mixpanel).
I am sending an "AppStart" event when the user launches the app and I start a timer.
I am sending an "AppStop" including the timer duration when the user stops the app (back button, history, home button, ...)
My first thought was to use the Activity Life Cycle Callbacks, but my app consists of several activities, and I don't want to send events for switching between those. 
How would you solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have one already, create an Android `Application` class, and use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` to have the following code run for all your activities `onResume`, and another one for all your activities `onPause`:

```
        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            if (counter == 0) {
                sendEvent("app-start")
            }
            counter++;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0) {
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (counter == 0) {
                            sendEvent("app-stop");
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
```

see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks)

Comment: This does not work: Lets say you switch from Activity A to B: A gets paused and then AFTER that B gets resumed. Your code would send an "app-start" each time you switch activity

Comment: this can be solved by delaying the app-stop event a bit, see edit. It's not bullet-proof, but we'll be ok for 99% of cases

Comment: Your code still does not work. Sends an app-start every time you switch to another activity. Which is just logical

Comment: Figured out a solution which seems to work. Can edit your post if you want.

Comment: Actually there is another problem with mixpanel: if you delay app-stop and the user leaves the app, you r trying to send the event at a time where mixpanel won't be available anymore. AFAIS mixpanel sends the last request immediately after you quit the app. After that no more requests are sent. So "app-stop" gets lost.

Comment: feel free to edit my code, i'll mark it as a community post. regarding mix-panel, how do they know when you've quit the app? if they know that, can't you get session measurement from mixpanel? most analytics tools measure sessions by timeout from last event sent

Comment: This solution worked for me in the end: https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-android/blob/d22c032a94beb9a3052d3c3d503c3bf1060f379f/src/main/java/com/mixpanel/android/mpmetrics/MixpanelActivityLifecycleCallbacks.java

Comment: well, it's pretty close to what i did here, maybe with some more verifications...